# How to check if a file is executable in Lua?

Tags: lua, file-attributes

How can I check in Lua if a string is the path to an executable file? It seems that neither the standard library nor, surprisingly, LuaFileSystem provides a way to do this.

Comment: Use `loadfile()` and check if it returns an error?

Comment: `loadfile` is for loading Lua code, not for checking if a file is binary executable, @hjpotter92.

Comment: @Omar, the way you phrased your question it seemed that you wanted to know how to check, if a file can be run within Lua (that is, if it is a Lua script). I got the same impression and that's why loadfile came up, I suppose...

Comment: Oh, OK, @W.B., I'll rephrase.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LuaFileSystem has the lfs.attributes() function which returns a table.  That, rather perversely, has a key named "mode" which contains a string describing the "type" of node (file, directory, socket, etc).

Although it's not listed in the manual at: http://keplerproject.github.io/luafilesystem/manual.html ... which seems to be the canonical reference for that module ... there is also a 'permissions' key in that table.  I think you could parse it for any "x" characters.

I discovered this with:

```
#!lua 
local lfs = require 'lfs'
attr = lfs.attributes('./some_file')
for name, value in pairs(attr) do
    print (name,value)
    end
```

Comment: Oh, that's what I get for reading documentation instead of experimenting in the REPL. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

[luaposix](https://github.com/luaposix/luaposix) has the [stat](http://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/docs/index.html#stat) function.  It returns a number for the `mode` field which includes execute permission bits (unlike LuaFileSystem which only gives you the file type.)

There is also [access](http://luaposix.github.io/luaposix/docs/index.html#access) which will check permissions for only the current user.